# How to proxy a static site using node.js

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a static site hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/3kh0/3kh0.github.io) and I want to see if I can use node.js and proxy it through a server. Say the normal URL is `https://example.com/js/app.js` the proxy would be `https://proxy.com/js/app.js` and it would just be a direct mirror of this site. Can I do this with express and http-proxy or how would I do this. I do not need any server resources, just it proxying the URL.